# Prevent Mobile Safari from scrolling address bar into view when clicking on top of the page

Tags: iphone, mobile, safari

I have a webapp that on load performs `window.scrollTo(0, 1);` to hide the address bar which is working.

One of the elements is a header with fixed positioning of `top: 0`, causing it to stay topmost of the viewport. On this header there are a few clickable buttons, when you try to click them, instead of performing the action it scrolls the address bar into view.
This is a default safari behavior for the click on the top 15-20 pixels of the screen.

I have tried to capture the clicks and cancel the event, cancel bubbling, prevent default etc. None of which seemed to work.

The code I tried was adding a div with id test:

```
#test {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us some of the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I use this for preventing default on mobile:

https://github.com/alexblack/google-fastbutton

```
$('#your-button').fastClick(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

});
```

No address bar is shown. Pretty neat for UX also

Comment: I am currently using fastclick.js (https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), and using the above method did not solve it either. For being certain I also tried with google-fastbutton and still no joy. Is it possible that this Safari behavior cannot be overridden?